# Azure speech to text gives "The recordings URI contains invalid data"

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text

I am trying to transcribe the text from an audio, I'm using the code provided by azure:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/batch/python/python-client/main.py

the problem is that it keeps telling me: Transcription failed: The recordings URI contains invalid data.

I don't understand how to fix this issue. The file is one hour long (220mb).

here is my transcription:

```
{'_self': None,
 'content_container_url': None,
 'content_urls': ['https://gruppofinservi7339283933.blob.core.windows.net/audio/giacomo3.wav?sv=xxx'],
 'created_date_time': None,
 'custom_properties': None,
 'dataset': None,
 'description': 'Simple transcription description',
 'display_name': 'Simple transcription',
 'last_action_date_time': None,
 'links': None,
 'locale': 'it-IT',
 'model': None,
 'project': None,
 'properties': {'channels': None,
                'destination_container_url': None,
                'diarization': {'speakers': {'max_count': 30, 'min_count': 1}},
                'diarization_enabled': True,
                'display_form_word_level_timestamps_enabled': None,
                'duration': None,
                'email': None,
                'error': None,
                'language_identification': None,
                'profanity_filter_mode': None,
                'punctuation_mode': None,
                'time_to_live': None,
                'word_level_timestamps_enabled': None},
 'status': None}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with some other small size file?

Comment: Yes, it used to work with an .m4a file got from a video to audio converter found online. Now I'm using moviepy to extract audio from video (codec='pcm_s16le', bitrate='256k', fps=16000) and the same audio as before, but with .wav extension is not working.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the below code to get the transcription of a **223 mb .wav** file from the Azure storage and successfully got the text output.*

**Code :**

```py
import logging
import time
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from swagger_client import Configuration

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",
    datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z"
)

SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = "<speech_key>"
SERVICE_REGION = "<speech_region>"

NAME = "Simple transcription"
DESCRIPTION = "Simple transcription description"

LOCALE = "it-IT"
RECORDINGS_BLOB_URI = "https://<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/kamSP.wav<SAS_token>"

TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 1200  
MAX_RETRIES = 5 

def check_audio_uri(uri):
    try:
        logging.info(f"Checking audio URI: {uri}")
        response = requests.get(uri, timeout=TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
        response.raise_for_status()
        logging.info("Audio URI is accessible.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error checking audio URI: {e}")
        raise

def transcribe_with_swagger_client(max_retries=MAX_RETRIES):
    logging.info("Starting transcription client...")
    check_audio_uri(RECORDINGS_BLOB_URI)

    config = Configuration()
    config.api_key['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
    config.host = f"https://{SERVICE_REGION}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"

    retry_strategy = Retry(total=max_retries, backoff_factor=2, status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504])
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)

    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.mount("https://", adapter)
        try:
            transcription_definition = {
                "contentUrls": [RECORDINGS_BLOB_URI],
                "displayName": NAME,
                "description": DESCRIPTION,
                "locale": LOCALE,
            }

            response = session.post(
                f"{config.host}/speechtotext/v3.1/transcriptions",
                json=transcription_definition,
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": SUBSCRIPTION_KEY},
                timeout=TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
            )
            response.raise_for_status()

            response_json = response.json()
            transcription_id = response_json.get("self", "").split("/")[-1]
            logging.info(f"Created new transcription with id '{transcription_id}' in region {SERVICE_REGION}")
            completed = False

            while not completed:
                time.sleep(5)
                response = session.get(
                    f"{config.host}/speechtotext/v3.1/transcriptions/{transcription_id}",
                    headers={"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": SUBSCRIPTION_KEY},
                    timeout=TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
                )
                response.raise_for_status()
                transcription = response.json()

                logging.info(f"Transcriptions status: {transcription['status']}")

                if transcription['status'] in ("Failed", "Succeeded"):
                    completed = True

                if transcription['status'] == "Succeeded":
                    response = session.get(
                        f"{config.host}/speechtotext/v3.1/transcriptions/{transcription_id}/files",
                        headers={"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": SUBSCRIPTION_KEY},
                        timeout=TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
                    )
                    response.raise_for_status()
                    pag_files = response.json()

                    for file_data in pag_files.get("values", []):
                        if file_data.get("kind") != "Transcription":
                            continue

                        audiofilename = file_data["name"]
                        results_url = file_data["links"]["contentUrl"]
                        results = session.get(results_url, headers={"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": SUBSCRIPTION_KEY})
                        logging.info(f"Results for {audiofilename}:\n{results.content.decode('utf-8')}")
                elif transcription['status'] == "Failed":
                    logging.info(f"Transcription failed: {transcription['properties']['error']['message']}")

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error during transcription process: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    transcribe_with_swagger_client()
```

I uploaded a **223 mb .wav** file to the storage account container as below,

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully and transcribes the text output as below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Reference :**

check this [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/768).